# How to set cell value in DataTable on button click

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to modify a cell value using DataTable (the new version) when an outside button is clicked.
I have the following for now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "development") {
        var cell = table.row( 6 ).data()[4]     
        cell.data( "development" ).draw();
    }
});
```

This doesn't work since I think the table row and data retrieval method doesn't return an object with .data() attribute that allows me to set data cell value. I'm getting the following error: `cell.data is not a function. (In 'cell.data( "development" )', 'cell.data' is undefined)`However, I'm not sure how to access a table cell value the .data() way without having a click even in the table. My button is placed outside the table somewhere else.

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

Since DataTables 1.10+ might not support fnGetNodes() as mentioned on the API landing page itself, instead now you can use rows().nodes().

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/28/

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({sorting : false});
var row = table.row(0).node();   

$('#test').on( 'click', function () {
    var text = "development";
    if (text == "development") {
       table.cell(row, 0).data('Development').draw();
    }
});
```

If you work with DataTables < 1.10 then you can use fnUpdate

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/29/

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({sorting:false});

$('#test').on( 'click', function () {
   var text = "development";
   if (text == "development") {
     oTable.fnUpdate('Development', 0, 0 ); // Single cell
   }
})
```

Comment: How do I do this with the sorting enabled?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fnUpdate` *Datatables Function* to update any specific cells just by row and col indexes.

something like this :

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('#button').click(function() {
    var row = document.getElementById("indexDepRow").value;
    var col = document.getElementById("indexDepCol").value;
    oTable.fnUpdate('development', parseInt(row), parseInt(col));
});
```

See [JsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/h9ty5Lsg/)